# Printing data from list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I have a list in my program declared with

```
List<List<object>> result = new List<List<object>>();
```

How can I print the data in `result` to the console?

Comment: What is the max length of the "result"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (var sublist in result)
{
    foreach (var obj in sublist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use linq:

```
foreach (var obj in result.SelectMany(l => l.Select(o => o)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linq try

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) extensions

Check out the following link for an example

[The Linq SelectMany Operator](http://www.codethinked.com/the-linq-selectmany-operator)